# writing to csv without a blank line from root

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I am writing something for a user to input a text file, search that file for a particular expression, and then write out all the instances of that expression to a csv file.

```
import re
import csv
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select File", filetypes=[("Text files", "*.txt")])

catalog = open(root.filename, "r")                                                            
contents = catalog.read()                                                                  

csvfiletypes = [('CSV Files', '*.csv')]
root.file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(title = "Save CSV File As", filetypes = csvfiletypes, defaultextension = csvfiletypes)
csvfile = root.file                

match = re.findall('[A-Z,\d]{6}\..{40,90}IDT=\d{1,10}', contents)    
#print(match)                                                                                                  

word = "IDT"                                            

for object in match:                                      
    start_index = object.find(word)                            
    extracted_string = object[start_index:]                  

    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow([object[:6] + "," + extracted_string])

catalog.close()
csvfile.close()
```

This gets me my output ok but with the blank line in between each instance of object in the csv file.

Usually when writing to csv I would use

```
csvfile = open('C:/Temp/Mycsv.csv', 'w', newline'')
```

to ensure that I don't get blank lines between my outputs. However if I try to use this replacing the file path with the 'root.file' above, then it just outputs a completely blank csv file. I have tried to find an alternative but no success so far. Any ideas as to how to achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you tried saving the result of `[object[:6] + "," + extracted_string]` to see if it is what you are assuming it is?

Comment: Use `filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(...)` instead of `root.file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(...)`, then `root.file = open(filename, "w", newline="")`.